# Android Spinner on click crashes the application

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have defined a spinner in my app that loads on start of the main activity. The activity loads successfully and also loads the spinner with the values from a String array from another class.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    AnotherClass ac = new AnotherClass();

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ac.array);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

On clicking on the spinner the app crashes with the following trace:

```
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619): java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:394)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getDropDownView(ArrayAdapter.java:415)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getDropDownView(Spinner.java:569)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropDownAdapter.getView(Spinner.java:565)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.widget.Spinner.measureContentWidth(Spinner.java:513)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.widget.Spinner$DropdownPopup.show(Spinner.java:739)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.widget.Spinner.performClick(Spinner.java:453)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
02-02 15:14:15.947: E/AndroidRuntime(1619):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: `ac.array` is null that's why it's throwing NullPointerException

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK That's weird. On load of the activity, the spinner loads the values from the array. At least the first value from the array is visible on the emulator.

Comment: just debug your code before sending Array to ArrayAdapter using Log and check you are getting all values in Array

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Got it. There was a mismatch between the size of the array and the elements I loaded into it. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

what i am finding in your code. there is resource not found in your code. so you have check it out.

```
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
// Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner layout
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
// Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
// Apply the adapter to the spinner
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

please refer more details http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html

Answer (score 0):

This is where I was going wrong:

```
array = new String[12];
array[0] = "JanuaryX";
array[1] = "FebruaryX";
array[2] = "March";
array[3] = "April";
array[4] = "May";
```

It should have been:

```
array = new String[5];
```